# Adding fully connected layers to CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I want to add a global averaging pooling layer followed by a few fully connected layers to this CNN architecture:

```
img_input = layers.Input(shape=(img_size, img_size, 1))
x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 1, padding = 'same')(img_input)
x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 2)(x)
x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 2)(x)
x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(3, 5, activation='relu', strides = 2)(x)

x = layers.Dense(200,activation='relu')
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)

output = layers.Flatten()(x)

model = Model(img_input, output)
model.summary()
```

But whenever I try to add a fully connected layer after the las Conv2D layer I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-370-1cf54963b964> in <module>
     11 x = layers.Dropout(0.1)
     12 
---> 13 output = layers.Flatten()(x)
     14 
     15 model = Model(img_input, output)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    885         # Eager execution on data tensors.
    886         with backend.name_scope(self._name_scope()):
--> 887           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    888           cast_inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
    889           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _maybe_build(self, inputs)
   2120     if not self.built:
   2121       input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(
-> 2122           self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
   2123       input_list = nest.flatten(inputs)
   2124       if input_list and self._dtype_policy.compute_dtype is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    161         spec.min_ndim is not None or
    162         spec.max_ndim is not None):
--> 163       if x.shape.ndims is None:
    164         raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +
    165                          layer_name + ' is incompatible with the layer: '

AttributeError: 'Dropout' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

my dataset looks like this:

```
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_test.shape)
(1600, 200, 200, 1) (400, 200, 200, 1) (1600, 3) (400, 3)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you forgot to call `Dropout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the functional API, you want to use:

```py
x = layers.Dense(200, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
```

Comment: thank you! that worked well.

Comment: and how can I add a global average pooling layer after the last Conv2D layer?

Comment: Just add `x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)` after the `Conv2D` layer, and you don't need the `Flatten` layer at the end